# Selected Item of Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I want to get selectedItem from the treeview on which the user right clicks using a context menu in a command parameter. I don't understand what should be the relative source here. Please help

```
        <Grid.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildSymbolList}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold">
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>  

            <TreeView Name="Tree" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}">
                <TreeView.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu StaysOpen="true">
                        <MenuItem Header="MyMenu" Height="20" Command="{Binding RemoveMyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}">
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TreeView.ContextMenu>

            </TreeView>
```

I get an error

Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TreeView', AncestorLevel='1''.

Comment: please share your `ItemTemplate` ChildTemplate

Comment: I have updated my question with the child template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <MenuItem Header="MyMenu" Height="20" Command="{Binding RemoveMyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
                    </MenuItem>
```

### ContextMenu.PlacementTarget Property

> Gets or sets the UIElement relative to which the ContextMenu is positioned when it opens.

Comment: That works. Thank you so much. Could you please explain this as well?

Comment: Actually contextMenu is not part of the same visual tree. So you can not find parent or Ancestor on context menu.